# Distance formula with $(0,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to work out the distance between two points: $(0,0)$ and $(5,-5)$.
Using the distance formula give's me an answer of $0$ which is not right.

For example:
$$
(0 - 5)^2 + (0 - (-5))^2) = (-25) + (25) = 0
$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax for mathematical formula and symbols: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $(0-5)^2=25$ not $-25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ is 
$$\sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2}$$
So it should be:
$$\sqrt{(0-5)^2+(0-(-5))^2}=\sqrt{(-5)^2+(5)^2}=\sqrt{25+25}=\sqrt{50}$$
Your mistake is that $(-5)^2 \neq -25$, but $(-5)^2=25$.